# Change size of system console as user

Tags: terminal, console

At uni, I'm using a terminal to log into a text console of some unix server. As the monitors are 17" and the console is displayed full screen, it's a bit annoying to look at the screen with the default column and row size.

Is it possible, as a user, to change the size of the console, either by increasing the number of rows & columns or by even decreasing the used resolution if the monitor (i.e. adding an unused border around it)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to figure out which utility controls the console. On *BSD it's vidcontrol(1). I'd do a man -k console and see what comes up.

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of command I have to look for? It's not BSD, so there is no vidcontrol. I have access to Solaris and Debian Linux I think..

Comment: @poke Sorry, I have no clue. From various explorations in google, this seems like a kernel loading option in linux.